# Could not find method addButtonClick on basic SQLite page

Tags: java, android, sqlite, onclick

I'm trying to get a basic SQLite database working in my app, but on my button click I'm getting the following error:

> Could not find method addButtonClicked(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'addButton'

**MemoActivity.java**

```
public class MemoActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText LInput;
    TextView LText;
    MyDbHandler dbHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_memo);
        LInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.LInput);
        LText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LText);
        dbHandler = new MyDbHandler(this, null, null, 1);
        printDatabase();
    }

    public void addButtonClicked(){
        Memos lyrics = new Memos(LInput.getText().toString());
        dbHandler.addLyric(lyrics);
        printDatabase();
    }

    public void deleteButtonClicked(){
        String inputText = LInput.getText().toString();
        dbHandler.deleteLyrics(inputText);
        printDatabase();
    }

    public void printDatabase(){
        String dbString = dbHandler.databaseToString();
        LText.setText(dbString);
        LInput.setText("");
    }

}
```

**activity_memo.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.test.test.app.MemoActivity">
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/LInput"
        android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
        android:width="300dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add"
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LInput"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/LInput"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/LInput"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:onClick="addButtonClicked" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/LInput"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/LInput"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:onClick="deleteButtonClicked" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/LText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/deleteButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="102dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work, the method must be public and accept a View as its only parameter. So, you need to pass `View` as parameter. 
Like this:

```
public void addButtonClicked(View view){
        Memos lyrics = new Memos(LInput.getText().toString());
        dbHandler.addLyric(lyrics);
        printDatabase();
}

public void deleteButtonClicked(View view){
    String inputText = LInput.getText().toString();
    dbHandler.deleteLyrics(inputText);
    printDatabase();
}
```

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) for more detailed explanation;

Comment: Thanks but now i get an error on the () of printDatabase(); saying printDatabase cannot be applied to view

Comment: Fixed. I had made a mistake, sorry.